# What is the maximum distance a trap can be installed from a shower drain?

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain

I am installing a new shower in an upstairs attic.  I am taking part of a downstairs closet for a chase wall to run the plumbing and electrical. The closet is 10' from where the shower drain will be located.  Rather than pull up good hardwood floor or tear out a plaster ceiling, I plan to push the drain line under the floor from the attic space near the closet.  I would like to locate the trap in the closet as that would be easier than pushing the trap assembly the 10' to the shower; not to mention that I am limited in the space between the floor and ceiling below.

Comment: Traps are supposed to be directly below the fixture outlet. 10 feet is too long even for a trap arm, the vent take off will need to be much closer to the shower.

Comment: @Bcworkz, you got that right, I had to look up the vent requirements for a job I am doing. Code requires the vent to be no farther than 6ft away from the drain opening.

Comment: Are you saying the space between the floor and the ceiling is not large enough to accommodate a trap? If this is the case, the joists are probably not large enough to support livable space.

Answer (score 1):

1. If a 3" pipe is run to a 2" trap the pipe is sufficiently oversized to be considered self venting.
2. A running trap may be used remotely which uses less space at the shower drain.
3. To answer the original question, I don't know the distance to trap max but it depends on the piping size.

Comment: In what plumbing code is self venting and running traps allowed?